# Disallowed Key Characters in Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, security, post, codeigniter-2

I'm getting this error while submitting my form. Have read similar questions but couldn't find my problem.

I just disabled '_clean_input_keys' function temporarily and printed the $_POST to see what's wrong. but could not see anything weird.

Where should I search for this disallowed character?

This is my $_POST:

```html
array (size=67)
  'Naam' => string '1' (length=1)
  'NaamKhanevadegi' => string '1' (length=1)
  'NaamPedar' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Shenasname' => string '1' (length=1)
  'CodeMelli' => string '1111111222' (length=10)
  'TarikhTavalodDay' => string '10' (length=2)
  'TarikhTavalodMonth' => string '10' (length=2)
  'TarikhTavalodYear' => string '1361' (length=4)
  'Jensiat' => string '1' (length=1)
  'MahalTavalod' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Khedmat' => string '1' (length=1)
  'SerialShenasname' => string '222222' (length=6)
  'Taahol' => string '1' (length=1)
  'SarparastHastam' => string '1' (length=1)
  'TedadeTakafol' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Ghad' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Jesmani' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Vazn' => string '2' (length=1)
  'SabegheBimari' => string '1' (length=1)
  'SabegheBime' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Bimegar' => string '1' (length=1)
  'BimeShode' => string '1' (length=1)
  'ShomareBime' => string '2' (length=1)
  'BimeDay' => string '28' (length=2)
  'BimeMonth' => string '8' (length=1)
  'BimeYear' => string '8' (length=1)
  'ShoruMostamariDay' => string '8' (length=1)
  'ShoruMostamariMonth' => string '8' (length=1)
  'ShoruMostamariYear' => string '1360' (length=4)
  'BimeBikari' => string '1' (length=1)
  'PayanMostamariDay' => string '8' (length=1)
  'PayanMostamariMonth' => string '8' (length=1)
  'PayanMostamariYear' => string '1360' (length=4)
  'Isargari' => string '1' (length=1)
  'NameHemayati' => string '1' (length=1)
  'PostalCode' => string '1212121212' (length=10)
  'Tel' => string '' (length=0)
  'Mobile' => string '09090909090' (length=11)
  'Email' => string '' (length=0)
  'Address' => string '' (length=0)
  'MarjaNaam' => string '' (length=0)
  'MarjaTel' => string '0909090909' (length=10)
  'MarjaMobile' => string '09090909090' (length=11)
  'Savad' => string '5' (length=1)
  'Reshte' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string '0' (length=1)
      3 => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => string '0' (length=1)
  'Moadel' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  'NoeDaneshgah' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
  'Mokaleme' => 
    array (size=1)
      ''.$i.'' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Neveshtan' => 
    array (size=1)
      ''.$i.'' => string '1' (length=1)
  'ZabanTasalot' => 
    array (size=1)
      ''.$i.'' => string '0' (length=1)
  'NoeMaharat' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  'DarajeMaharat' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  'Gavahiname' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => string '11' (length=2)
  'NaameMoasese' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  'SabegheJobTitle' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
  'SabegheKar' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  'DarkhastiJobTitle' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
  'NoeEstekhdam' => string '1' (length=1)
  'ShahreDarkhasti1' => string '' (length=0)
  'ShahreDarkhasti2' => string '' (length=0)
  'ShahreDarkhasti3' => string '' (length=0)
  'KhodEshteghali' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Kharej' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Keshvar1' => string '' (length=0)
  'Keshvar2' => string '' (length=0)
  'Comment' => string '' (length=0)
  'Tamas' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

That little $ in $i made the problem.

I forgot some php tag there.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases when you have a existing software and you are trying to deploy in a new enviroment this kind of error should be caused by the PHP property

```
short_open_tag
```

Check if you have enabled in your new enviroment. In other words PHP couldn't read the tags in your code.